# matlab: упрощение выражений

Tags: математика, matlab, expressions, formula

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему Matlab упорно не хочет упросить выражение:

```
syms x

f = str2sym('1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma*x)*exp(-(((log(x)-mu)/sigma)^2)/2)')

g = diff(f)

f1 = subs(f, x, str2sym('e^(mu - sigma^2)'))

s1 = simplify(f1)


f1: (2^(1/2)*e^(sigma^2 - mu)*exp(-(mu - log(1/e^(sigma^2 - mu)))^2/(2*sigma^2)))/(2*sigma*pi^(1/2))
```

упрощённое выражение

```
s1: (2^(1/2)*e^(sigma^2 - mu)*exp(-(mu - log(1/e^(sigma^2 - mu)))^2/(2*sigma^2)))/(2*sigma*pi^(1/2))
```

т.е. вообще не упростилось, хотя должен был бы две экспоненты объединить в одну и логарифм экспоненты схлопнуть

в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что логарифм от экспоненты не равен, вообще говоря, исходному числу, если оно комплексное. Например, `log(exp(2*pi*i+1))=1`. Поэтому MATLAB не упрощает такие выражения. Если какая-то переменная, например `x`, в выражении всегда вещественная, то надо сообщить об этом матлабу с помощью вызова `assume(x,'real')`. Тогда он сможет упростить всё так, как нужно:

```
syms x sigma mu
assume(x,'real'); 
assume(sigma,'real');
assume(mu,'real');
f = 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma*x)*exp(-(((log(x)-mu)/sigma)^2)/2)
g = diff(f)
f1 = subs(f, x, exp(mu - sigma^2))
s1 = simplify(f1)
```

(У меня 2015b и `str2sym` у меня нет, поэтому я немного изменил код)